# C# Sql ADO.Net DataColumn error adding nullable Guid column

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to invoke a sql stored procedure from C#. I have the following code to create the DataColumn. But getting error while createing a DataTable when adding nullable Guid and DateTime type.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEntity.FirstName), typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEntity.DateOfBirth), typeof(DateTime?)),
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEmployerEntity.SectorId), typeof(Guid?)),
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEntity.EPortfolioId), typeof(int?))
        });
        dt.Rows.Add(
            learnerEntity.FirstName,
            learnerEntity.DateOfBirth ?? SqlDateTime.Null,
            learnerEntity.Employer?.SectorId ?? SqlGuid.Null.Value,
            learnerEntity.EPortfolioId ?? SqlInt32.Null.Value);
```

The error is:

```
DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.
```

Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong here?

I am trying the following:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEntity.FirstName), typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEntity.DateOfBirth), Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(LearnerEmployerEntity).GetProperty("DateOfBirth").PropertyType)),
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEmployerEntity.SectorId), Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(LearnerEmployerEntity).GetProperty("SectorId").PropertyType)),
            new DataColumn(nameof(LearnerEntity.EPortfolioId), Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(LearnerEmployerEntity).GetProperty("EPortfolioId").PropertyType))
        });
        dt.Rows.Add(
            learnerEntity.FirstName,
            learnerEntity.DateOfBirth ?? SqlDateTime.Null,
            learnerEntity.Employer?.SectorId ?? SqlGuid.Null.Value,
            learnerEntity.EPortfolioId ?? SqlInt32.Null.Value);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try googling the error? The problem is `typeof(Guid?)` and `typeof(DateTime?)`. By default columns are already nullable. Use `typeof(Guid)`, `typeof(DateTime)` and `typeof(int)` instead

Comment: But getting the error when the value is set. "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Comment: Use `DBNull.Value` or just `null`. A DataTable has .NET types like string, int, DateTime, Guid, not povider-specific types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialize it with `DBNull.Value`. But since there is no implicit conversion between your nullable types and that you will produce ugly code. It's better to use the [`SetField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.setfield?view=net-5.0) extension method that supports nullables:

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
row.SetField<string>(nameof(LearnerEntity.FirstName), LearnerEntity.FirstName);
row.SetField<DateTime?>(nameof(LearnerEntity.DateOfBirth), LearnerEntity.DateOfBirth);
row.SetField<Guid?>(nameof(LearnerEmployerEntity.SectorId), learnerEntity.Employer?.SectorId);
row.SetField<int?>(nameof(LearnerEntity.EPortfolioId), LearnerEntity.EPortfolioId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Raw ADO.Net doesn't understand or use Nullable types (it pre-dates them). Instead, you must set (or not) the `AllowDBNull` property on each DataColumn.

I'd really ***love*** to see a hypothetical "ADO.Net v2" that does away with DBNull in favor of Nullable types (and also for DataRow and DataReader to implement the same IDataRecord interface, but that's another story), but I find it unlikely we'll ever see this.

Comment: When setting the AlloDBNull , i am getting "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values." error