# "DataSet does not support System.Nullable" while assigning a nullable datatype to a table column

Tags: c#, dataset, nullable

I need to put empty values in some column of my DataTable. Empty values does not mean DBNull values but strict nulls. So, for this purpose I assign column's datatype as follows:
`myTable.Columns.Add("MyCol", typeof(decimal?));`
But the compiler says "DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>".

Is there any way around this? I don't want to substitute zeroes for nulls while inserting values in the table, like this:
`myRow["MyCol"] = val == null ? 0m : val;`
because it makes a difference in my program whether inserted value has been null or not. I also cannot substitute DBNulls for nulls while inserting values, like this:
`myRow["MyCol"] = val == null ? DBNull.Value : (decimal?)val;`
because compiler says "error CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'decimal?'

I googled for this issue and found just two similar cases:
https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/514233-adding-nullable-datetime-column-datatable-does-not-work
https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1542262
Both, however, do not have a solution that would work for me.

So, the only option I could invent was NOT assigning the value when it is null:

```
if (val != null) myRow["MyCol"] = val;
```

Is this the only way? And is there really no way to make DataSet support System.Nullable, so that code
`myTable.Columns.Add("MyCol", typeof(decimal?));`
be valid?

Comment: You have to write your own converter. Are you sure you want to do all this yourself? It's quite a hassle. ORMs like Entity Framework or Dapper would handle all this for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define a column as nullable in System.Data.DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953738/define-a-column-as-nullable-in-system-data-datatable)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67075823/6717178

Comment: @JHBonarius, the question "Define a column as nullable in System.Data.DataTable" partially does answer my question, thank you. I will make a complete answer and post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [JHBonarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6717178/jhbonarius), I got the main idea from one of those answers: [Define a column as nullable in System.Data.DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953738/define-a-column-as-nullable-in-system-data-datatable) The idea is to cast everything to object. First of all, there is no need to set table column's AllowDBNull property to true, since it is true by default. Second, I stuck with the line of code `myRow["MyCol"] = val == null ? DBNull.Value : (decimal?)val;` because of compiler error CS0173. The solution here is to cast both parts to object, like this: `myRow["MyCol"] = val == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)val` This works without error, and DBNull value is inserted in the table column. That's it.